# Animate constraint change in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewanimation, nslayoutconstraint

I have a slider in my table cell, and when the user slides it, I'm reloading that particular cell to show the updated slider value in my cell.

And when the user moved the slider to the max, i Want to change the width constraint of an element in my cell with some animation.

Everything works but I couldnt see the animation.

```
-(void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender{

    sliderValueChanged = YES;
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;

    int sliderValue;
    sliderValue = roundf(slider.value);
    [slider setValue:sliderValue animated:YES];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self getIndexPathForView:slider];

    MySliderCell *sliderCell = (MySliderCell *)[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    sliderCell.sliderValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",sliderValue];

    if(sliderValue == 7){
        [sliderCell layoutIfNeeded];
        sliderCell.radioButonWidth.constant = 40;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                         animations:^{
                             [sliderCell layoutIfNeeded];
                         }];
    }else{
        [sliderCell layoutIfNeeded];
        sliderCell.radioButonWidth.constant = 0;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                         animations:^{
                             [sliderCell layoutIfNeeded];
                         }];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    DLog(@"slider value :%d change method called, indexpath is %@",sliderValue,indexPath);


}
```

I have also tried usig `setNeedsUpdateConstraints`, and calling `layoutIfNeeded` on `self.tableView` instead of `cell`. But nothing worked. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I would guess that the reload rows call lays out the cell again and it is not animated.

Comment: If I remove the reload table call, then the cell wouldn't be updated with the slider value! IS there any work around ?

Comment: What else do you need updated on the cell? You already seem to set the values such as sliderValueLabel.

Comment: Generally unless the cell needs resizing the table view should not be used. You only modify the values internally in the cell.

Comment: even though I set the sliderCell.sliderValueLabel.text, it doesnt show up unless I call the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: Then that is another bug. I would put a breakpoint and check if the sliderCell is not nil. If you get the cell then this code should work normally. But in general I would suggest you to put the outlets into the cell itself and maintain everything inside it. If you need to report the changes to the view controller (or whatever parent) you should use a protocol-delegate procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try the suggested way and update the question.

Comment: @MaticOblak placing the outlet actions inside the cell, and animating it inside the cell class worked. PLease post an answer, so I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your example is that you call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in the same loop as the animation block. Generally all you would need to do is remove that call and the animation should work.

As from the comments it would seem that without calling it not even the text is changed in the cell which leads to the issue that you are probably not getting a correct cell when requesting it from the slider action method.

I suggest you to always use all the outlets of the cell inside a subclass of the table view cell. This way you can always be sure you have access to the correct subviews without calling `getIndexPathForView`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and in some cases then getting an object from your data source array with that index path like `myObject = self.array[indexPath.row]`. By doing so the only downside is to get the notification from the cell back to the table view owner (usually the view controller). For that case you generally use custom delegates where the cell would have a weak reference to the delegate (the view controller) and call the delegate on any action needed. To give an example of such table view cell:

**Header:**

```
@class MyTableViewCell;

@protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)myTableViewCell:(MyTableViewCell *)sender changedSliderValue:(CGFloat)newValue;

@end

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomObject *myObject; // The object this cell is designed to represent


@end
```

**Source:**

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)setMyObject:(MyCustomObject *)myObject {
    _myObject = myObject;

    // Set any UI properties needed
    self.slider.value = myObject.magnitude;
}

- (void)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {

    self.myObject.magnitude = sender.value;
    [self.delegate myTableViewCell:self changedSliderValue:sender.value];

    // Your animation code goes here as well

}

@end
```

So when you dequeue the cell you would then do something like:

```
MyTableViewCell *cell = ...
cell.delegate = self;
cell.myObject = self.myArray[indexPath.row];
```

And if you need the notification inside the view controller when the cell slider has changed you simply implement the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

How about use [UIView animateWithDuration:animations:completion:], and accept a completion block as parameter in your "sliderValueChanged" method then you can reload the tableView in the block and you can remove the reference of the tableView.